# Would a box2D sensor fit my needs?

Tags: box2d, cocos2d

I have a object in my game that when the main character hits it, all I want to do is have the object explode and then notify the character object that a hit has occurred.

Would I use a `b2Body` and set it as a sensor for this or would I achieve this some other way?

I'm using cocos2d by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it would work nicely. Don't forget that you will need to create a ContactListener for your application in order to be notified of the collision.

Here's an implementation I used from before, to get you started - it might need some tweeks due to being a year old

```
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "b2Contact.h"
class ContactListener : public b2ContactListener
{
public:
    ContactListener();

    void* userData; /// Use this to store application specific body data.
    void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact); // When we first contact
    void EndContact(b2Contact* contact); // When we end contact
};

#import "ContactListener.h"
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "b2Contact.h"
#import "GameScreen.h"

// Implement contact listener.
ContactListener::ContactListener(){};

void ContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    // Box2d objects that collided
    b2Fixture* fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
    b2Fixture* fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();
    // Sprites that collided
    CocosNode* actorA = (CocosNode*) fixtureA->GetBody()->GetUserData();
    CocosNode* actorB = (CocosNode*)  fixtureB->GetBody()->GetUserData();

    // This is only true if for example a sprite touched something in your box2d simulation that was not a sprite such as the ground
    // You may not want to return here, so keep that in mind
    if(actorA == nil || actorB == nil) return;

    // Information about the collision, such as where it hit exactly on each body 
    b2WorldManifold* worldManifold = new b2WorldManifold();
    contact->GetWorldManifold(worldManifold);

    // Maybe you wanna handle it differently but for this example, we're going to simply use our global object (see previous post)
    // To store the gamescene where these bodies exist and tell it they collided
    [[Global instance]._gameScene onActorDidStartContact:actorA against:actorB at:worldManifold];
}

    // Implement contact listener.
void ContactListener::EndContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    // Box2d objects that collided
    b2Fixture* fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
    b2Fixture* fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();
    // Sprites that collided
    CocosNode* actorA = (CocosNode*) fixtureA->GetBody()->GetUserData();
    CocosNode* actorB = (CocosNode*)  fixtureB->GetBody()->GetUserData();

    // This is only true if for example a sprite touched something in your box2d simulation that was not a sprite such as the ground
    // You may not want to return here, so keep that in mind
    if(actorA == nil || actorB == nil) return;

    // Information about the collision, such as where it hit exactly on each body 
    b2WorldManifold* worldManifold = new b2WorldManifold();
    contact->GetWorldManifold(worldManifold);

    // Maybe you wanna handle it differently but for this example, we're going to simply use our global object (see previous post)
    // To store the gamescene where these bodies exist and tell it they collided
    [[Global instance]._gameScene onActorDidEndContact:actorA against:actorB at:worldManifold];
}

-(void) onBunnyDidLandOnCar:(GameObject*)actor
{
     // Nothing to see here, game ended already
    if(self._gameIsOver) return;
    // Cast the actor as the car
    Car* car = (Car*) actor;
    // Check if landing was valid
    if(car._body->GetPosition().y + 3.0f > _junny._body->GetPosition().y) { // Too far below the roof of the car to count as landing on it
        //NSLog(@"onJunnyDidLandOnCar: Too far below");
        return; 

// Do some other stuff
...
}
```

Comment: There's no point in having a `void *userData` on your b2ContactListener subclass. Since you can only have one ContactListener at a time, you should be adding the data fields you need, typed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that sounds like something a sensor should be used for.

As far as I'm aware, sensors should be used for any objects that don't actually cause a collision response with objects it collides with.

In this case, you don't want the player to actually be moved when it hits the sensor (or the reverse). A sensor is definitely what you want.